# Make doesn't rebuild a project after some changes

Tags: c++, makefile

My C++ project has some unit tests. When I change test code Make doesn't see or compile it. But when I change C++ class code Make rebuilds it correctly.
This is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS := -std=c++11

SRCDIR := src
SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))

TESTDIR := test
TESTSOURCES := $(shell find $(TESTDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))

BUILDDIR := build
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

TARGET := bin/main
TESTTARGET := bin/test

MAINS := build/main.o
TESTOBJECTS := $(filter-out  $(MAINS), $(OBJECTS))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)


$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<


test: $(TESTTARGET)

$(TESTTARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -L/usr/include/unittest++ $(TESTOBJECTS) $(TESTSOURCES) -lunittest++  -o $(TESTTARGET)



clean:
    rm $(BUILDDIR)/*.o
    rm $(TARGET)
    rm $(TESTTARGET)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `target` and `test` targets depends on `$(OBJECTS)`, which is independent of `TESTSOURCES`. So what you described is expected behaviour.

EDIT: A working example may looks like this (not verified)

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS := -std=c++11

SRCEXT := cpp
BUILDDIR := build

SRCDIR := src
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
TARGET := bin/main

MAINS := build/main.o

TESTDIR := test
TESTSOURCES := $(shell find $(TESTDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
TESTOBJECTS := $(patsubst $(TESTDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(TESTSOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
TESTOBJECTS += $(filter-out $(MAINS), $(OBJECTS))
TESTTARGET := bin/test

MAINS := build/main.o

.PHONY: target test clean
all: target


# Objects
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<


target: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)


test: $(TESTTARGET)
$(TESTTARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(TESTOBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)   $(OBJECTS) $(TESTOBJECTS) -o $(TESTTARGET) -L/usr/include/unittest++ -lunittest++

clean:
    rm $(BUILDDIR)/*.o
    rm $(TARGET)
    rm $(TESTTARGET)
```

Comment: Change the test dependency to `$(TARGET) $(TESTTARGET)` as suggested, and add rules for `TESTOBJECTS` just like what you do with `OBJECTS` and `target`

Comment: I used this. But `make test` cannot compile sources from `TESTSOURCES` - it has not rules to compile test code. Maybe I should compile test code as source code and consolidate it in next step.

Answer (score 0):

You should only compile your test files when you need them (when running `make test`), there's no point compiling them when simply running `make` (your `all` target).

I'd also suggest that you change the `test` target to:

```
test: $(TARGET) $(TESTTARGET)
```

so that if you only did a change in your (non testing) code, it will also get picked up.

Another suggestion could be so that you also run `$(TESTTARGET)` after compiling it (part of `test` target), so that the tests are run when running `make test`.